# Zend Framework can not read keys without "zfcahce:" prefix?

Tags: zend-framework, redis

I am unable to read Redis data from zend framework, which is added from 'Redis Client' (console) without key prefix "zfcache:".

Example:

```
SET mykey 'myvalue'
```

when i check for mykey from zf $redis->hasItem('mykey'), i get false.

Now setting a key with prefix of "zfcache:" works

```
SET zfcache:mykey 'myvalue'
```

now i can read this data from zend, $redis->hasItem('mykey') returns true and i get value using $redis->getItem('mykey')

help me in reading redis keys without prefix 'zfcache:' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with Default namespace value, zfcache.

[click here for zend storage options](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html#basic-configuration-options)

to remove the default namespace, set to empty in RedisFactory.php

```
$redisOptions = new RedisOptions ( ["namespace" => ""] );
```